# Extract data from table cells and ignore specific child tags with Xpath?

Tags: html, parsing, xpath

Having this html table:

```
<table class="info">
<tbody>
    <tr><td class="name">Year</td><td>2011</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="name">Area</td><td>45 m<sup>2</sup></td></tr>     
    <tr><td class="name">Condition</td><td>Renovated</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to extract data from 2-nd cell in each row (it is: 2011, 45 m, Renovated)

I use this Xpath expression:

```
//table[@class="info"]//td[2]//text()
```

Received output (wrong):

```
2011
45 m
2
Renovated
```

Desired output:

```
2011
45 m
Renovated
```

As you can see, from the 2-nd row I received value that is enclosed in **`<sup>`** tags. I want to exclude this value.
I know that instead of my current Xpath code I can use this one (removed 1 slash in the end):

```
//table[@class="info"]//td[2]/text()
```

It will solve problem, but I need to exclude this specific **`<sup>`** tag inside **`<td>`**. Because sometimes I have some tags inside **`<td>`** that I do not want to exclude.

So, I want to get data from 2-nd cell in each row and exclude value in **`<sup>`** tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every `tr` get the second `td` and get the `/text()` (single slash) to avoid getting the element children texts. Worked for me:

```
//table[@class="info"]//tr/td[2]/text()
```

Prints:

```
2011
45 m
Renovated
```

---

Or, if you want to exclude `sup` element only:

```
//table[@class="info"]//tr/td[2]//text()[not(parent::sup)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it because it ignores all child tags. But I need to ignore only <sup> tag. Sometimes I have subtags that I do no want to exclude. I wrote that in my question.

Comment: I am sorry I guess I missed something, but it still does return value in <sup > tags. Something is wrong in expression.

Comment: @AndreyRadik interesting, it works for me. Make sure youa re trying the same expression as I've provided.

Comment: Very strange. Does not work in http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester but I checked it on freeformatter.com. Everything works. Thanks.